# How do I create a android webview mobile app with jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, android-webview, jquery-mobile-listview

I am pretty new to jQuery.I have heard of building mobile web apps with jquery mobile. I plan to open up a list view in jquery with horizontal navigation to sublists and further to a detailed page , sort of like a menu to submenu to a detailed page with images and text. Is there a way I can acheieve this in jquery? Also planning to add the jquery index.html? file in my android project and call it via webview. I just need some demo apps regarding listview and sublist navigation to detailed pages as reference. Anyone has any idea regarding the same?

Thanks!
Justin.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for a start, you could check [the demo API in here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/). You'll get a pretty demonstration of the listview, different widget you could use in JQM. For Android Webview, I can't help though

Comment: Thanks,I saw that.However, do you know if jqm has any demo for list category >list subcategory> detailed page? I am looking to make a menu with sub menus upon navigation and then details of the food item. any clue?Any standalone jqm project will be great to practice on,I can handle the webview part, just need help with jqm